Circuit power outage monitoring
I am using an STM32F4 series MCU in my project. What can I do to detect when the mains power is cut and to find out how long the system has been off?

Use an ADC port and detect the voltage

You need a battery powered real time clock IC, a battery powered RAM, a power down interrupt and some lines of code. The interrupt should be triggered when the mains power is cut and the MCU is running with the energy stored in the capacitors of the power supply unit for some final milliseconds.
The power down interrupt service routine should store the time from RTC to the RAM before going to sleep.
The power up interrupt service routine checks the time stored in the RAM with the time from the RTC to find out how long the system has been off.
